# Is there tg protocol url to open known contact in Telegram desktop?

Tags: telegram

I need to open Telegram Desktop clicking some link on a web page. Is there any way to open Telegram and switch to chat with known contact? I tried "send message" URL like `tg://msg?to=+79501231234&text=Hi` but it just opens Telegram without opening 'to' contact chat.

There is `tg://resolve?domain=USERNAME` that works with user names, but I need it to work with phones.

Answer (score 0):

tg://resolve?phone=11111 should work